# Security implications of using Self-Issued Providers in OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Are there any major security drawbacks to using [Self-Issued Providers](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SelfIssued) with OpenID Connect? (And the Implicit flow that those imply/require?)

As opposed to, say, using Dynamic Client Registration?

We're working on a project that requires decentralized cross-domain authentication, where server/client pre-registration is difficult or impossible. Which means we need to pick one of those two mechanisms, it sounds like? (Self-Issued Providers or Dynamic Client Registration). Which of those is more appropriate for what sort of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-issued providers and Dynamic Client Registration are serving different purposes.

Self-issued providers are self-hosted or possibly in-browser OpenID Connect Providers that would not have a trust relationship with Relying Parties. They provide the equivalent of self-registration to RPs and provide "non-asserted" identity.

Dynamic Client Registration lets Clients/RPs register themselves with OpenID Connect Providers to dynamically create a trust relationship so that the Provider can provide 3rd-party asserted identity to the Client.

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt answer! Can you give an example of when you would want to use Self-Issued Providers? (And explain a little more by what you mean by "non-asserted identity"?)

Comment: a Relying Party would accept Self-issued providers if it seeks an alternative for the "self-service" signup/registration webpages that it would have to send through users otherwise